# How to grep for pointers to pointers (in C++ source)?

Tags: grep

I have been using `grep` to perform recursive search of text inside a directory, i.e.

```
grep -Hrn "some-text" ./
```

However, I am running into some troubles when I need to search for pointers or pointers of pointers:

```
grep -Hrn "double**" ./
> grep: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

I have made some attempts to go around this, including some I found via Google searches:

```
grep -Hrn "double[**]" ./
grep -Hrn "double[*][*]" ./
```

but neither seems to work. Any pointers?

Comment: The `grep "double[*][*]"` should work. `but neither seems to work` - how do you detect that?

Comment: @KamilCuk I got a blank output, which shouldn't be the case since there are plenty inside the directory.

Comment: Are there `double**` ? Are you sure you don't want `double **`?

Comment: Pretty sure - someone wrote other parts of the code and he is pretty strict with code styles so I can't imagine him making that rookie error :D

Comment: @QuangThinhHa A declaration like `double **i` is no error (assuming C).

Comment: Ah damn... Sorry folks you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `*` by using `\`. For example

```
$ echo "double***" | grep "double\*\*\*"
double***
```

If you don't escape `*` it matches the character before the `*` zero or more times. One `*` would therefore match e.g. `doubleeeee` but the second `*` results in an error since the operand (the character before the `*`) is not valid since it's again `*`. That's exactly what the error message tells you.

The version using `[]` should also work. As mentioned in the comments the issue might be that your variable declarations contain whitespace. The following regex matches these (now using the `*` operator):

```
$ echo "double  **" | grep "double\s*\*\*"
double  **
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use fixed strings, like:

```
grep -FHrn "double**" ./
```

(the `-F`)

```
 -F, --fixed-strings
     Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e., force grep to
     behave as fgrep).
```

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=&n=1 (also same in `rg` and GNU grep)